# Copy all records from Table1 to Table2, and insert seperate data into Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have two tables. They have an identical structure except for the fact that Table2 has one more column. I want to create a stored procedure that copies all the data from Table1 to Table2, and then insert data into the unique column in Table2. I am kinda stumped, all I have so far is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_t_p @t_p INT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_2
    SELECT * FROM table_1
END
```

where @t_p is the data that I want to insert. This is going to be constant for all the records being copied over. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 SELECT *, @t_p FROM table_1
```

Note that you should really enumerate the columns in both the `insert` and `select`, like:

```
INSERT INTO table_2(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, @t_p FROM table_1
```

This makes it much easier to ensure that each column from the source table is going into the relevant target column, possibly makes the query resilient to changes in the data structures, and allows you to handle structures where columns  have different orders.

Comment: do i not need to specify which column in table_2 the variable @t_p is being inserted into? EDIT: your edit answered this question, I'll give it a try

Comment: @fragElephant: with this syntax, it goes to the last column. But you really should enumerate the columns, as explained in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (col1, col2, . . . , col_extra)
    SELECT col1, col2, . . ., @t_p
    FROM table_1 ;
```

Listing the columns is a good habit that ensures that your code works with fewer errors and is not prone to issue if the table structures change -- or the columns are declared in a different order.